# node.js sequelize: multiple 'or' and 'and' operator

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

How to do this in sequelize? I need to use operator 'or' after/inside the operator 'and'

```
SELECT
    *
FROM 
    dbo.bdi_user2
WHERE
    (username = 'test' OR email = 'test' )
    AND (senha = '123' OR password = '123')
```

I tried as below, but I couldn't

```
database.models.User.findAll({
            where: {
                $or: [
                    { username: username },
                    { email: username },
                ],
                $and: [
                    { pwd: password },
                    { password: password }
                ]
            },
            logging: console.log
        })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this

```
database.models.User.findAll({
            where: {
                $and: [
                 {
                   $or: [
                      { username: username },
                      { email: username },
                   ]
                },
                 {
                   $or: [
                    { pwd: password },
                    { password: password }
                   ]
                 }
                ]
            },
            logging: console.log
        })
```